# Gradle dependencies cache in project directory

Tags: android, git, maven, gradle, dependency-management

I have some dependencies from Maven Central Repository in my project. So I thought what if any dependency will be removed from Maven Central and other repositories (GitHub) and I will not be able to find this dependency somewhere and build my project?

I want to add local dependency cache to git repository of my project, so anyone could clone this repository and build my project offline. May be in Cocoapods way. How can I do this?

Comment: Finally, I developed a solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/31662782/746347

Comment: possible duplicate of [Gradle - download dependencies, lock versions and update dependencies manually](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31662781/gradle-download-dependencies-lock-versions-and-update-dependencies-manually)

Answer (score 1):

You already have a local maven repo, add `mavenLocal()` under project's `repositories` section. I doubt if any dependency from maven or other public hosted repos could be removed but the best way to prevent yourself from this is to host own repo - `artifactory` for instance. Other way is to add all the dependencies to version control system and configure `gradle` to read dependencies from flat file repository. [Here](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sec%3arepositories) is the whole chapter on repositories in gradle docs.

Comment: Please, see my comment to @Steffen answer

Comment: Dependencies in flat directory could have its own dependencies and I have to search all dependency tree by myself to build and run my project. But what I want is to use benefits of gradle dependency-management, but also add add dependency cache to source conrol so anyone could build project without connection to internet or access to artifactory and also if some dependencies will be removed from Maven Central in the future.

Answer (score 1):

In an enterprise environment you would use a repository manager like [Archiva](http://archiva.apache.org/index.cgi), [Artifactory](http://www.jfrog.com/home/v_artifactory_opensource_overview) or [Nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/). You can configure these tools to behave as a proxy for public repositories so that all needed artifacts are cached on demand.

These tools are installed to a server so that every developer can access them and the build is set up to only have this repository so that all artifacts are cached if they aren't already available in the cache.
[There's a page at Codehaus comparing the above mentioned tools](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Maven+Repository+Manager+Feature+Matrix).

If a repository manager is too much for you, you have to manage the local repository by yourselves.

Comment: I like the way dependency management done with Cocoapods or NuGet. Using these tools I write dependencies in specific file (Podfile or add them via Visual Studio or NuGet command line) and then they are downloaded from remote repository to specific project folder and I can add them to source control. I do not have enterprise environment and I do not want to manage dependencies by my own using flat directory repository.

Comment: As far as I know iOS devs still discuss if Pod's dependencies should be checked into source control. In general these are just different approaches to same problem. It's impossible to be done in gradle with such a way. You can configure gradle to download dependencies to specific folder and add this folder as a dependencies location. See here: http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/how_do_i_tell_gradle_where_to_download_dependencies_to