# Gradle - download dependencies, lock versions and update dependencies manually

Tags: java, android, gradle, dependency-management

**The issue.**

Gradle dependency management made so:

- there is no easy way to check availability of dependencies updates (only using some third-party plugins like [ben-manes/gradle-versions-plugin](https://github.com/ben-manes/gradle-versions-plugin)) and download updates replacing old versions;
- dependencies artifacts are downloaded from remote repositories and then stored in gradle cache and reused in succeeding builds; but successful compilation of your project must not depend on having a connection to Internet, availability of remote repositories and existence of specific versions of dependencies in these repositories.

**The goal.**

- download and store all dependencies artifacts in VCS;
- manually check updates for these dependencies and download them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My solution works for Gradle configuration using `java` or `android` plugins.

`java` plugin defines `compile` and `testCompile` configurations.
`compile` is for dependencies that are required to compile the production source of the project. `testCompile` is for dependencies that are required to compile the test source of the project.

Let's define our own configurations in `build.gradle`:

```
configurations {
    download
    testDownload
}
```

Next let's create directories:

- `libs/compile/downloaded` is where `download` dependencies will be stored;
- `libs/testCompile/downloaded` is where `testDownload` dependencies will be stored.

Next we define several tasks.

Delete dependencies from `download` configuration:

```
task cleanDownloadedDependencies(type: Delete) {
    delete fileTree('libs/compile/downloaded')
}
```

Delete dependencies from `testDownload` configuration:

```
task cleanDownloadedTestDependencies(type: Delete) {
    delete fileTree('libs/testCompile/downloaded')
}
```

Download dependencies from `download` configuration:

```
task downloadDependencies(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.download
    into "libs/compile/downloaded/"
}
```

Download dependencies from `testDownload` configuration:

```
task downloadTestDependencies(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.testDownload
    into "libs/testCompile/downloaded/"
}
```

Execute all above tasks to update dependencies:

```
task updateDependencies {
    dependsOn cleanDownloadedDependencies, cleanDownloadedTestDependencies, downloadDependencies, downloadTestDependencies
}
```

Next we define our dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    download(
            'com.google.code.gson:gson:+',
            'joda-time:joda-time:+',
    )
    testDownload(
            'junit:junit:+'
    )
```

And then we tell where `compile` and `testCompile` configurations should take dependencies used for compilation.

```
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs/compile', include: '**/*.jar')
    testCompile fileTree(dir: 'libs/testCompile', include: '**/*.jar')
}
```

Now you can download or update already downloaded dependencies:

```
./gradlew updateDependencies
```

If you are using `android` plugin then you can also add `androidTestDownload` configuration for dependencies that are required for compilation and running tests on Android device. Also some dependencies can be provided as `aar` artifacts.

This is the example for Gradle configuration using `android` plugin:

```
...

repositories {

    ...

    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs/compile', 'libs/compile/downloaded',
                'libs/testCompile', 'libs/testCompileDownloaded',
                'libs/androidTestCompile', 'libs/androidTestCompile/downloaded'
    }
}

configurations {
    download
    testDownload
    androidTestDownload
}

android {
    ...
}

dependencies {
    download(
            'com.android.support:support-v4:+',
            'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+',
            'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:+',
            'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:+',
            'com.vk:androidsdk:+',
            'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:+',
            'oauth.signpost:signpost-core:+',
            'oauth.signpost:signpost-commonshttp4:+',
            'org.twitter4j:twitter4j-core:+',
            'commons-io:commons-io:+',
            'com.google.code.gson:gson:+',
            'org.jdeferred:jdeferred-android-aar:+'
    )
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs/compile', include: '**/*.jar')
    testCompile fileTree(dir: 'libs/testCompile', include: '**/*.jar')
    androidTestCompile fileTree(dir: 'libs/androidTestCompile', include: '**/*.jar')
}


task cleanDownloadedDependencies(type: Delete) {
    delete fileTree('libs/compile/downloaded')
}

task cleanDownloadedTestDependencies(type: Delete) {
    delete fileTree('libs/testCompile/downloaded')
}

task cleanDownloadedAndroidTestDependencies(type: Delete) {
    delete fileTree('libs/androidTestCompile/downloaded')
}

task downloadDependencies(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.download
    into 'libs/compile/downloaded/'
}

task downloadTestDependencies(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.testDownload
    into 'libs/testCompile/downloaded/'
}

task downloadAndroidTestDependencies(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.androidTestDownload
    into 'libs/androidTestCompile/downloaded/'
}

task updateDependencies {
    dependsOn cleanDownloadedDependencies, cleanDownloadedTestDependencies, cleanDownloadedAndroidTestDependencies, downloadDependencies, downloadTestDependencies, downloadAndroidTestDependencies
}

fileTree(dir: 'libs/compile', include: '**/*.aar')
        .each { File file ->
    dependencies.add("compile",
            [name: file.name.lastIndexOf('.').with { it != -1 ? file.name[0..<it] : file.name }, ext: 'aar'])
}

fileTree(dir: 'libs/testCompile', include: '**/*.aar')
        .each { File file ->
    dependencies.add("testCompile",
            [name: file.name.lastIndexOf('.').with { it != -1 ? file.name[0..<it] : file.name }, ext: 'aar'])
}

fileTree(dir: 'libs/androidTestCompile', include: '**/*.aar')
        .each { File file ->
    dependencies.add("androidTestCompile",
            [name: file.name.lastIndexOf('.').with { it != -1 ? file.name[0..<it] : file.name }, ext: 'aar'])
}
```

Comment: It looks ok, you can write a plugin for all the tasks which will handle most of the tasks automatically. Despite I understand the goal I'm not fan of keeping dependencies in VCS. In iOS development (with Pods) there's still a war about it - to keep dependencies under VCS or not ;) +1!

Comment: Good idea about plugin! I'll try.

Comment: Just ask in case of any problems.

Comment: @Opal About keeping dependencies under VCS. Every project has some prerequisites and requirements for successful build - operating system, tools (eg Java, Gradle, Android SDK), internet connection, remote repositories, etc. I always reduce amount of these requirements to the reasonable minimal set of absolutely required tools (OS, Java, Gradle, Android SDK). If I do not include dependencies in VCS then I include them in project as git modules, which repositories are on the same host as repository of original project.

Comment: That may look like paranoia, but it's better than missing required dependencies if they will be deleted from maven repository or cocoapods.

Answer (score 2):

For locking versions of downloaded dependencies (library/ etc versions to hard-coded versions) for making the builds reproducible, now Gradle 4.8 and onwards, we'll have  inbuilt "dependency lock" support. This will help greatly to make builds reproducible if someone is using dynamic versions (M.m.p/i) Major.minor.patch/interimBranch etc (ex: 4.+ or 3.1.+) or version range for pulling artifacts from a binary repository tool (ex: Artifactory / Nexus).

Any Gradle user who is using Gradle version 4.8+ should start using this new feature.
https://docs.gradle.org/4.8/userguide/dependency_locking.html
For Gradle 4.8 Release Notes: https://docs.gradle.org/4.8/release-notes.html

In past, this dependency lock feature was provided to Gradle community and made available via a FOSS plugin available to Gradle from Netflix Nebula's https://github.com/nebula-plugins/gradle-dependency-lock-plugin and https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/nebula.dependency-lock

Comment: that's nice that we have it as an internal built-in part of gradle to update locks but... what about modifying that lock state in other ways? (deletion, being able to ignore it when in development, etc.)